# Chunked Memory Allocation - Recent Interesting Job Interview Question for C Developers

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic, struct

**Question**

> Implement  **XXX new_malloc(unsigned int size)**, a function that allocates memory on the heap and returns a pointer to the allocated struct. The limitation is that you must use simple_malloc. Keep in mind that the allocated memory is **not continuous**. You can choose how to implement the XXX struct as you wish.

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 256 
void* simple_malloc() {
    return malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
}
```

**My idea**

> Define a struct (Buffer) that will hold the number of chunks and a pointer to all the pointers that will hold the address of the allocated chunk(ChunkBuffer). Since we deal with dynamic memory allocation, the pointer in the struct, will be stored along with the size of the array.

**Example**
The user asks to allocate 1362 bytes. We calculate the total number of chunks by dividing the required size by the BUFF_SIZE --> 1362/256 = 5 and we add 1 if size % BUFF_SIZE ---> 82 > 0 is greater than zero. We get total of 6 ChunkBuffer.

**Allocation.h**

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 256 
void* simple_malloc() {
    return malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
}
// Stores chunk of allocated space
typedef struct ChunkBuffer {
    unsigned int chunk_size; // Total number of bytes allocated
    void* allocated_chunk_ptr; // Allocated buffer for the chunk
}ChunkBuffer, *ChunkBufferPtr, **ChunkBufferTable;

// Stores the collection of the different chunks
typedef struct Buffer {
    unsigned int chunks_size; // Total chunks number
    ChunkBufferTable chunk_buffer_tbl; // Array of all the allocated chunks
}Buffer, *BufferPtr;

void* simple_malloc(); // Given function
BufferPtr new_malloc(unsigned int); // Allocation by chunks
int calc_chunks(unsigned int, int); // Help function to calculate the number of needed chunks
```

**Allocation.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Allocation.h"


/* Calculate the amount of needed chunks */
int calc_chunks(unsigned int size, int buff_size) {
    int num_chunks = size / BUFF_SIZE;
    int mod = size % BUFF_SIZE;
    return 0 < mod ? ++num_chunks : num_chunks;
}

BufferPtr new_malloc(unsigned int size)
{
    BufferPtr buffer_ptr = NULL;
    int num_chunks = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    /* Sanity check */
    if (0 >= size) {
        return NULL;
    }

    num_chunks = calc_chunks(size, BUFF_SIZE);

    /* Allocating the data structure that will hold the required allocated space */
    if (!(buffer_ptr = (BufferPtr)malloc(sizeof(Buffer)))) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Allocating the array that will hold the chunks of data */
    if (!(buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl = (ChunkBufferTable)malloc(sizeof(ChunkBufferPtr) * num_chunks))) {
        goto buffer_cleanup;
    }
    buffer_ptr->chunks_size = num_chunks;

    /* Allocating each chunk */
    for (; i < buffer_ptr->chunks_size; i++) {

        buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[i] = (ChunkBufferPtr)malloc(sizeof(ChunkBuffer));

        if (!(buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[i]->allocated_chunk_ptr = simple_malloc())) {
            goto chunk_cleanup;
        }
    }

    /* Allocation success */
    return buffer_ptr;

chunk_cleanup:
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[j]->allocated_chunk_ptr);
    }
table_cleanup:
    free(buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl);
buffer_cleanup:
    free(buffer_ptr);
    return NULL;
}
```

**The problem is that I get C6386, C6011, C6385 error for this section of the above code(Thank you rici):**

1. Warning **C6386**   Buffer overrun while writing to 'buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl':  the writable size is 'sizeof(ChunkBuffer *)*num_chunks' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written
2. Warning **C6011**   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[i]'
3. Warning **C6385**   Reading invalid data from 'buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl':  the readable size is 'sizeof(ChunkBuffer *)*num_chunks' bytes, but '8' bytes may be read

```
    /* Allocating each chunk */
    for (; i < buffer_ptr->chunks_size; i++) {

        buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[i] = (ChunkBufferPtr)malloc(sizeof(ChunkBuffer));

        if (!(buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[i]->allocated_chunk_ptr = simple_malloc())) {
            goto chunk_cleanup;
        }
    }
```

> 1. I don’t understand where I’m not allocating the memory properly **and why**.
> 2. Also, why there is a possible buffer overflow if I’m always allocating space for the struct and then allocate space for the inside pointers?

Comment: I haven't got a clue what those error numbers mean since they are specific to your compiler. You're generally better off quoting the error messages in full.

Comment: I updated the question with the included messages.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I get these warnings when I try to build the project using VS2019. I tried to explain everything in detail and added comments.

Comment: My guess is that your compiler thinks num_chunks might be 0. Also, after you set  `buffer_ptr->chunk_buffer_tbl[i]` to the result of calling `malloc`, you immediately dereference without verifying that the allocation succeeded.

Comment: Thank you so much rici!

Problem solved!